# I cannot transmit audio data to my Express server via WebSocket

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, mediarecorder

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script>
    let socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
    var mediaRecorder;
    socket.addEventListener('open', (event) => {
      // Allowing access to the microphone
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
        .then((stream) => {
          // Initializing the media recorder
          mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
          mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = event => {socket.send(event.data)};
        });
    });
    
    // Starting the media recorder after a delay (2 seconds)
    setTimeout(a => {mediaRecorder.start()}, 2000)
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**server.js**

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');

const app = express();
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ noServer: true });

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // Serving the index.html file
  res.end(readFileSync('index.html'));
});

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  ws.on('message', (message) => {
    // Logging the received message
    console.log(message);
  });
});

// Handling WebSocket upgrade
httpServer.on('upgrade', (request, socket, head) => {
  wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, (ws) => {
    wss.emit('connection', ws, request);
  });
});

// Listening on port 8080
httpServer.listen(8080);
```

The server is up and running, and microphone access has been granted successfully without any error codes in both terminals. However, messages are not being logged in the server terminal. Can you help resolve this issue?

On the client-side, it should read microphone input data and send this data to the server in real-time.